# will $\inf${${|x-y|:x \in S,y \in T}$}$>0$ if we remove condition of compactness.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

A theorem in my real analysis book states,

> If S and T are disjoint compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ prove that $d(S, T) > 0$,
> where $d(S, T)= \inf${${|x-y|:x \in S,y \in T}$}.

My question is will the $d(S,T)>0$ still holds if we remove the condition of compactness given in theorem?

$P=${${|x-y|:x \in S,y \in T}$} contains distance between all the points of set $S$ and $T$.

$\inf(P)=0$ means distance between points of set $S$ and $T$ can be made as small as we please,
that is for a given $\epsilon$, $\exists $, $x \in S$ and $y \in T$, such that

$|x-y|<\epsilon$.

Comment: What is the distance between $\mathbb N$ and $\{n+\frac 1 n): n \geq 2\}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it's a infinite set ,with infimum zero?

Comment: distance between nth element of $\mathbb{N}$and {$n+{1 \over n}$} tends to zero for sufficiently large n.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you give example of disjoint sets $S$ and $T$, such that they are bounded but not closed(hence not compact) but $\inf${$d(S,T)}=0 $ still holds.

Comment: $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$.

Comment: It still holds if we require one of the sets to be compact, and the other one to be merely closed.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated inf$(P)=0$ means that $S$ and $T$ are arbitrary close, let's kill one of the compactness hypothesis from the theorem you have cited, so we can take for example $S=(0,1]$, while we choose $T=\{x\}$ with $x \in \mathbb R$, so $T$ is compact (actually as much compact as possible, it's a set made up of a single element!) while $S$ it is not.

Can you think of any choices for $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $x$ is arbitrary near to $S$ yet not in $S$?

> $x=0$